# kubernete-master stuck in waiting

Tags: 18.04, juju, kubernetes

Why kubernete-master workload stuck on waiting? message is:

```
Waiting for kube-system pods to start
```

And when I run

```
sudo juju scp kubernetes-master/1:kubectl ~/bin/kubectl
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR exit status 1 (scp: kubectl: No such file or directory)
```

when looking at kube-system namespace on  pod coredns I see this. it seems it can not get images:

`Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                   From                           Message
  ----     ------          ----                  ----                           -------
  Warning  Failed          84m (x11 over 119m)   kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed          50m (x283 over 119m)  kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff         29m (x368 over 119m)  kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Back-off pulling image "coredns/coredns:1.4.0"
  Normal   SandboxChanged  23m                   kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Failed          20m (x4 over 23m)     kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Failed to pull image "coredns/coredns:1.4.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Failed          20m (x4 over 23m)     kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed          20m (x6 over 23m)     kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling         18m (x5 over 23m)     kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Pulling image "coredns/coredns:1.4.0"
  Normal   BackOff         3m44s (x73 over 23m)  kubelet, juju-06819a-0-lxd-71  Back-off pulling image "coredns/coredns:1.4.0"`

Comment: I have this same problem -- except the waiting message is "waiting to retry addon deployment". Attempting to hit the API while proxied results in a 502. I remember installation taking a long time -- but is this thing really going to take this long to come back up after a reboot? Seems a bit absurd...